# makefile same executable with different dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a makefile that creates the same executable (`EXE`) but for different purposes, (The `*.o` files in `OBJ_DIR` are built with a separate rule, not shown here)

```
FILE1 = ... some list of files ...
FILE2 = ... different list of files...

myexe1: $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(FILE1))| $(BIN_DIR)
    $(F90) -o $(EXE) $^ $(FFLAGS)

myexe2: $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(FILE2))| $(BIN_DIR)
    $(F90) -o $(EXE) $^ $(FFLAGS)
```

I can call the make with `make myexe1` and `make myexe2` and build the `EXE`.
But as the `EXE` is not `myexe1` or `myexe2`, the build is triggered every time the `make myexe1/myexe2` is called. But what I want, is when `myexe1` is called it should check if `EXE` is updated and then it should trigger the build. I can make `myexe1` a phony target to achieve this partially, like

```
FILE1 = ... some list of files ...
FILE2 = ... different list of files...

myexe1 : $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(FILE1))| $(BIN_DIR)
    $(F90) -o $(EXE) $^ $(FFLAGS)
```

But then I can not run the `myexe2` anymore. Is it possible that when `myexe1` or `myexe2` is called it should check if the `EXE` and the associated object files are updated, and only then it should trigger the build process?

Answer (score 2):

This is an odd requirement.  But I recommend you build the unique target, then copy it to the common target as a side-effect:

```
FILE1 = ... some list of files ...
FILE2 = ... different list of files...

myexe1: $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(FILE1))| $(BIN_DIR)
        $(F90) -o $@ $^ $(FFLAGS)
        cp $@ $(EXE)

myexe2: $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(FILE2))| $(BIN_DIR)
        $(F90) -o $@ $^ $(FFLAGS)
        cp $@ $(EXE)
```

Now whichever one of `myexe1` or `myexe2` was last built, will be the one in the `$(EXE)`.